# How can a script run by a user logged-in over ssh, get the user's public key?

Tags: ssh, sshd, key-authentication

I need to get the users public key, that was used to authenticate the current ssh session.

Running `env` only shows:

```
SSH_CLIENT=192.168.1.2 35538 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.1.2 35538 192.168.1.3 22
```

Comment: How about reading from ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub?

Comment: I am interested, what will you use it for?

Comment: @Panki what if you have several public key and you rely on a ssh.conf that you cannot manage yourself. also ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub is not readable from your ssh connection.

Comment: Do you have access to the sshd logs? It's confusing, because you seem to be asking how to find the ssh key that you just used (as that user).

Comment: Potentially useful: https://serverfault.com/a/888300/293440

Comment: also: `ssh -v remote-host exit 2>&1 | grep publickey`; that indicates successful key login; grep for `debug1: Offering .*key:` for the actual key